# How can i trigger 2 different Jenkins jobs by pushing 2 different branches?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have two different jobs (project-prod, project-dev) in Jenkins. project-prod fetchs the code from */master to prod server and project-dev does it for for */dev branch. Also i have 2 different hooks from bitbucket to jenkins/project-prod and jenkins/project-dev. But when i push to master branch both 2 jobs are being triggerred and also it is the same scenario for pushing to dev branch. 
What i need is, when i push to master branch only jenkins/project-prod job should be triggered and when i push to dev branch only jenkins/project-pdev job should be triggered.
Via git plugin i configured the branches to build but failed.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you add a screen copy of the git plugin configuration? (for both jobs)

Comment: Could you please share the code of your hooks ?

Comment: @BrunoLavit here is my git config. 
Repository URL https://bitbucket.org/company/project
Credentials: username/pass
Branches to build : */master (*/dev for other)

Comment: @VitaliiElenhaupt hook works well.

Comment: The git plugin configuration seems normal. When you look at a build that you believe was triggered incorrectly, what does Jenkins identify as the cause (for example, "Started by SCM change"). Are the two jobs building the correct branches (does project-dev build */dev and project-prod build */master)? Can you elaborate on what "failed" when you configured the branches to build?